# Referral Network & Rewards

Tags: python

I want to be able to distribute a total reward among network, where the distribution diminishes according to the depth of the network but the total sum of distributed rewards equals the initial total reward.

I have attempted to model this with:

\$S = a * (1 - r^n) / (1 - r)\$

The below Python snippet presents this series.

```py
def distribute_total_reward(total_reward: float, decay_rate: float, max_levels: int = 10) -> list:
    # Solve for the first term (a)
    a = total_reward * (1 - decay_rate) / (1 - decay_rate ** max_levels)
    rewards = [a * (decay_rate ** i) for i in range(max_levels)]
    return rewards


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Total reward to be distributed
    tw = 3500

    # 50% Decay rate for the distribution
    dr = 0.5

    # Number of levels in the network
    ml = 8

    reward_distribution = distribute_total_reward(tw, dr, ml)
    for level, reward in enumerate(reward_distribution, start=1):
        print(f"Level {level} referrer receives: £${reward:.2f}")

    print(f"Total Distributed: ${sum(reward_distribution):.2f}")
```

Note: I have arbitrarily set `tw`, `dr`, `ml`.

One of the things I have struggled with is building out the solution to support circular referrals. I think this sort of breaks a referral system designed with hierarchy because anyone can referrer anyone else. **I want to accommodate the flexibility of reverse referrals (i.e., downstream referring upstream and vice versa)**.

I have tried implementing a fixed reward for reverse referrals, separate from the main referral rewards. However, I feel like this is too simplistic as it assumes a fixed number of reverse referrals. Realistically, we need to dynamically identify these reverse referral scenarios and allocate accordingly. Here is the code:

```py
def distribute(
    total_reward: int,
    decay_rate: float,
    max_levels: int = 10,
    reverse_referral_reward: int = 5
) -> tuple:
    """
    Distributes the total reward among the referral network and handles reverse referrals.
    """
    num_reverse_referrals = 2
    adjusted_total_reward = total_reward - (num_reverse_referrals * reverse_referral_reward)

    a = adjusted_total_reward * (1 - decay_rate) / (1 - decay_rate ** max_levels)
    rewards = [a * (decay_rate ** i) for i in range(max_levels)]
    reverse_rewards = [reverse_referral_reward for _ in range(num_reverse_referrals)]
    return rewards, reverse_rewards


if __name__ == "__main__":

    total_reward = 3500           # Total reward to be distributed
    decay_rate = 0.5              # Decay rate for the distribution
    max_levels = 8                # Number of levels in the referral network
    reverse_referral_reward = 5   # Reward for reverse referrals

    primary_rewards, reverse_rewards = distribute(
        total_reward,
        decay_rate,
        max_levels,
        reverse_referral_reward
    )
    for level, reward in enumerate(primary_rewards, start=1):
        print(f"Level {level} primary referrer receives: ${reward:.2f}")

    for i, reward in enumerate(reverse_rewards, start=1):
        print(f"Reverse referral {i} receives: ${reward:.2f}")

    print(f"Total Distributed Reward: ${sum(primary_rewards) + sum(reverse_rewards):.2f}")
```

Comment: Can you add descriptions for all of the variables in your expression at the top?

Comment: I have applied this to the new edit.

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 5 → 1. Please see [_What should I do when someone answers my question?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## clear identifiers

`distribute_total_reward()` looks great.
All the identifiers are very helpful.
An URL citation of that formula which introduces
the variable "a" wouldn't hurt.

## post-condition

The essential aspect of this routine is the computed rewards
shall sum to the specified input parameter.
We should minimally spell this out with an English sentence
in a docstring.
The supplied test code nicely computes a sum(),
but it is not self-evaluating so a human must
eyeball the result and verify it's sensible.

Ideally the function would end with an `assert` of equality, but due to FP
[ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place)
rounding errors we expect a small epsilon error,
so the test would be for relative_error() less than e.g.
1 [ppb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parts-per_notation#Parts-per_expressions).

An easy assert would be to construct a
[unit test](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase)
to check the post-condition.
For some parameters, such as 1024 total reward and .5 decay rate,
the FP result will yield exact equality.

## def main()

Nice `__main__` guard.
There is starting to be enough code here
that it may be worth burying it within `def main():`.
By the time you introduce `reverse_rewards` we're definitely ready for that.
I confess I'm not sure about the choice of `tw` rather than a `tr` name.

nit: We switch between `£$` and `$` currency prefixes.

## distribute()

It's unclear why the currency figures of `total_reward`
and `reverse_referral_reward` would be of type `int`.
Please understand that a `float` annotation
[subsumes `int`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#the-numeric-tower),
even though integers can have unlimited magnitude
and there's no inheritance relationship between them.

We have a docstring, and it is informative.
But it's a little wishy washy.
If I'm tasked with writing a unit test
that verifies correct behavior,
verifies the implementation conforms to a spec,
then consulting just the docstring, alas, won't suffice.
The verbs "distributes" and "handles" are OK but they
aren't accompanied by any specifics.

It seems like we want a pair of post-conditions here,
constraining what happens with each of the two reward categories.

## DRY

```
    adjusted_total_reward = total_reward - (num_reverse_referrals * reverse_referral_reward)
    ...
    reverse_rewards = [reverse_referral_reward for _ in range(num_reverse_referrals)]
```

These are kind of saying the same thing.
Consider first computing

```
    reverse_rewards = [reverse_referral_reward] * num_reverse_referrals
```

and then you can conveniently assign `total_reward - sum(reverse_rewards)`.

## design of Public API

```
    return rewards, reverse_rewards
```

This *kind* of looks like we're returning parallel vectors `a, b`
as seen in many Fortran APIs, where `a[i]` describes one
aspect of entity `i` and `b[i]` another aspect of that same entity.
But of course they have different lengths.
Consider including `0` values in the reverse_rewards.
Consider returning a single vector of
[namedtuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)
that contain values for both reward categories.

Which brings us to the input parameters.
You will need a way to describe who referred, in which direction,
and how effectively.
This could be a general
[graph](https://pypi.org/project/networkx),
but I am skeptical that you have a business use case for that yet.
Better to start out with a restricted graph such as a tree.
Maybe pass in a vector of (forward, reverse) referral magnitudes,
and of course when all the reverse values are zero we should produce
same result as that first algorithm produces.

## algorithm

The closed-form solution you provide is very nice.
Here is another way, a little messier, to think
about that initial algorithm.
Assign total_reward to the initial entry, with the rest zero.
Use a `for i in range(max_levels):` loop
to make several passes over the vector,
distributing a small fraction of remaining reward each time.
The last iteration makes the one and only assignment to the final level.
We always {add, subtract} same small value, preserving a constant total.

Now consider a graph that includes reverse referrals.
Again we make several passes over the graph starting from its root,
distributing a fraction as we go.
But when following an upward edge we now can distribute upward, as well.

The current approach of “divide level I reward evenly among that level’s participants” will need to move toward considering each participant individually.

It's possible that you wish to view this as "a single (downward)
origin node plus N (upward) reverse nodes",
and so you want to run N + 1 instances of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Applying @J_H suggestions, I am adding this answer as reference for any future readers.

```py
def distribute(total_reward: float, decay_rate: float, max_levels: int) -> list:
    """
    Distributes a total reward across a referral network based on a geometric decay rate.

    This function calculates the initial reward amount for the first level and then applies
    a decay rate for subsequent levels, ensuring that the sum of all rewards is as close as
    possible to the total_reward. The geometric series formula used is: S = a(1-r^n)/(1-r),
    where S is the total sum of rewards, a is the first term, r is the common ratio (decay rate),
    and n is the number of terms (levels).

    Post-condition: The sum of the computed rewards is approximately equal to the specified
    total_reward, allowing for floating point rounding errors.

    :param total_reward: The total reward amount to be distributed (float).
    :param decay_rate: The decay rate for the distribution of rewards (float).
    :param max_levels: The number of levels in the referral network (int).
    :return: A list of reward amounts for each level (list of floats).
    """
    # Calculate the first term of the geometric series
    first_term = (total_reward * (1 - decay_rate)) / (1 - decay_rate ** max_levels)

    # Generate the list of rewards for each level
    rewards = [first_term * (decay_rate ** i) for i in range(max_levels)]

    # The sum of rewards should be close to the total_reward
    assert abs(sum(rewards) - total_reward) / total_reward < 1e-9, (
        "The sum of distributed rewards does not match the total reward."
    )

    return rewards


def main(total_reward: float, decay_rate: float, max_levels: int = 10):

    reward_distribution = distribute(total_reward, decay_rate, max_levels)
    for level, reward in enumerate(reward_distribution, start=1):
        print(f"Level {level} primary referrer receives: ${reward:.2f}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(total_reward=3500, decay_rate=0.5)
```